# code for this in css and jsp

Tags: jsp

whenever a code format (means any code written in c or c++, or any other language) is found , the background color changes itself to grey , else all the text(theoritical part) remains in the same white background, how this can be done using css and jsp.

Comment: you expect the jsp to parse the site contents in search of code keywords? How would it tell if 'if' is the 'if' keyword or the 'if' english word? You need to rethink your problem or rephrase your question.

Comment: well i have no idea how to do it, i think we need to parse the contents.Otherswsise u tell me how it should it be done.

Comment: "unknown (google)", how are you attempting to learn programming languages. You appear to be trying to cover many different programming languages and making errors such as in structuring that beginners usually learn when starting to learn a programming language. Are you actually attempting to consult online resources at all? There of course is nothing wrong with asking for help, but learning a programming language doesn't mean start typing gibberish immediately, because in one of your questions you leave out braces, which I would believe would be very hard to do even as a starter.

Answer (score 0):

Will need to define a span or div with a particular id or class assigned, then just define a background colour for that id or class in your css and it'll be done.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're doing is something like a forum, use a method of wrapping code. It's not a major inconvenience, as you can see on SO you have spacing in front of lines, and on forums using BBcode you'll have things like [code].

In any case, trying to automatically detect code is not a very good idea, as false positives could easily be triggered.

Then take the code and wrap it in a tag like <code>, and style it. Stack Overflow isn't an education site, so learn about CSS yourself. Searching things on the internet isn't hard... unless you've never used the internet.